# Script to loop and copy all files from command output

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying something like this:

```
rpm -ql `rpm -qa | grep openssh-5`
```

This lists all the files that are installed using the openssh-5 rpm.

I wish to copy all these files to a folder: eg: myfolder

So i try this:

```
cp ``rpm -ql `rpm -qa | grep openssh-5`` myfolder
```

but it fails.
Is there any way out, any shell scripts as such?

Comment: Did you try to copy them inside a loop one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't nest backticks. this should work:

```
cp $(rpm -ql $(rpm -qa | grep openssh-5)) myfolder
```

anoter way would be:

```
rpm -qa | grep openssh-5 | xargs -d $'\n' rpm -ql | xargs -d $'\n' cp -t myfolder
```

(this also handles filenames containing spaces. won't handle filenames with newlines tough...)

Comment: And what happens if a file name contains whitespace? Hmmm?

Comment: @glglgl i'd usually use the `xargs`-version with the `-0` switch, but i don't know how to get rpm to print it's output null-terminated. so i've updated it to use `\n` as delimiter. if you consider that unix-filenames can contain newlines also, then that isn't 100% secure either. but personally, given that files in rpm packages follow the convention of not using whitespace in filenames, i'd just use the simpler first form.

Comment: `\n` as delimiter is ok. I talked about the first version with `cp $(...`. Your `xargs` version is a very acceptable way.

Answer (score 0):

```
files=${rpm -ql `rpm -qa | grep openssh-5`};

while read file do
    cp $file "myfolder";
done < $files;
```

maybe?

Comment: `${...}` is for paramenter expansion, and `cp` doesn't need a `>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rpm -qla \*openssh-5\* | while read filename; do
    cp -a "$file" "$myfolder"
done
```

. Note the `""` around the variables which takes account for whitespace in filenames (which are, admittedly, quite rare in RPM packages - but not impossible).

Note as well the `rpm -qla` construct which makes things easier.